# Why i still have errores if i disable new relic module in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.4, newrelic

I have magento 2.4.4
I removed new relic module.

but when I do a inspection on my website. I havea a new relic error. How can i get newrelic out of my system.

I also stoped new relic service on my server.

```
POST https://bam.nr-data.net/1/NRJS-3b583d56b6b427adda9?a=1336092316&v=1.236.0&to=YFUAMkpUXkUAUkZeCVkfIwVMXF9YTlJTQwdbXwVJW1REUwZeQE5JQVkHEQ%3D%3D&rst=4876&ck=0&s=d910333c61455143&ref=https://www.ebest.cl/outdoor/hidratacion/hidratacion-botellas.html&af=err,xhr,stn,ins,spa&ap=1225&be=1402&fe=3252&dc=667&at=TBIDRAJOTUs%3D&perf=%7B%22timing%22:%7B%22of%22:1689350201945,%22n%22:0,%22u%22:1421,%22ue%22:1421,%22f%22:6,%22dn%22:6,%22dne%22:6,%22c%22:6,%22s%22:6,%22ce%22:6,%22rq%22:11,%22rp%22:1402,%22rpe%22:1473,%22di%22:2069,%22ds%22:2069,%22de%22:2069,%22dc%22:4647,%22l%22:4647,%22le%22:4655%7D,%22navigation%22:%7B%7D%7D&fp=1831&fcp=1831 net::ERR_FAILED 402 (Payment Required)
```

also this one

```
hidratacion-botellas.html:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://bam.nr-data.net/1/NRJS-3b583d56b6b427adda9?a=1336092316&v=1.236.0&to=YFUAMkpUXkUAUkZeCVkfIwVMXF9YTlJTQwdbXwVJW1REUwZeQE5JQVkHEQ%3D%3D&rst=4876&ck=0&s=d910333c61455143&ref=https://www.ebest.cl/outdoor/hidratacion/hidratacion-botellas.html&af=err,xhr,stn,ins,spa&ap=1225&be=1402&fe=3252&dc=667&at=TBIDRAJOTUs%3D&perf=%7B%22timing%22:%7B%22of%22:1689350201945,%22n%22:0,%22u%22:1421,%22ue%22:1421,%22f%22:6,%22dn%22:6,%22dne%22:6,%22c%22:6,%22s%22:6,%22ce%22:6,%22rq%22:11,%22rp%22:1402,%22rpe%22:1473,%22di%22:2069,%22ds%22:2069,%22de%22:2069,%22dc%22:4647,%22l%22:4647,%22le%22:4655%7D,%22navigation%22:%7B%7D%7D&fp=1831&fcp=1831' from origin 'https://www.ebest.cl' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors you're encountering are related to the New Relic agent, which is usually installed on your server to monitor performance. It can provide data about things like page load time, transaction tracing, etc. But if you have uninstalled New Relic module and stopped its service on your server, you should not be seeing these errors.

Here's a few steps you can take to completely remove the New Relic references from your Magento system:

Disable the New Relic reporting in Magento:
You can disable New Relic reporting from the Magento Admin.

On the Admin sidebar, go to Stores > Settings > Configuration.
In the left panel, expand General and choose Web.
Expand the New Relic Reporting section and set Enable New Relic Integration to No.
Save the configuration.
Check if there is any hard coded script:
Sometimes, there might be hard coded New Relic scripts present in your Magento theme or custom modules. Check the layout XML files and template phtml files for any scripts related to New Relic and remove them.

Clear Cache:
Clear your Magento Cache to ensure that the changes are reflected.

Check .htaccess file:
If the New Relic agent was installed at the server level, it could have injected a line into your .htaccess file. Check this file to see if there is a line about New Relic and remove it.

Check your server's php.ini file:
New Relic's PHP agent might be loaded via your php.ini file. Check your php.ini file for any reference to New Relic and remove it. Don't forget to restart your web server (Apache or Nginx or whatever you are using) afterwards.

Remember to take a backup before making any changes. If you're not sure about these steps, it might be wise to consult with a Magento developer or a system administrator who can safely make these changes.

Comment: I did most of the things you recomended. But finally I did a sudo apt-get remove newrelic-php5
and restart apache and fpm and it worked. thanks